# Why peewee ignores column's unique definition?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am trying to create tables `User` and `Task`. In `User` I make `user_id` column unique, but peewee ignores it. There is no unique column when I look :

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = DBConfig.db

class User(BaseModel):
    user_id = IntegerField(unique=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'User'

class Task(BaseModel):
    task_content = TextField(null=False)
    completed = BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    user_id = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tasks', field='user_id', on_delete='CASCADE', on_update='CASCADE',
                              null=False)

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'Task'
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class User(db.Model):
    user_id = IntegerField(unique=True)

User.create_table()
```

Results in the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "user_user_id" ON "user" ("user_id")
```